# msgget function is not implemented

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, ipc, communication

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define  BUFF_SIZE   1024

typedef struct {
   long  data_type;
   int   data_num;
   char  data_buff[BUFF_SIZE];
} t_data;


int main(){

   key_t      msqid;
   int      ndx   = 0;
   t_data   data;


   msqid = msgget( (key_t)1234, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
   if ( -1 == msqid)
   {
      perror( "msgget() fail");
      exit( 1);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

and next, i do

```
gcc -o parent parent.c
```

and next,

```
./parent
```

but the result is

```
msgget() fail: Function not implemented
```

I don't know why the msgget function is not implemented even though this is just simple code.
How can i fix my code??

Comment: Are you really running this on Linux or in WSL?

Comment: msgget() is one of those old SYSV APIs that might not be available on more modern POSIX systems (they use the mq_ functions).

Comment: if you're using a WSL then this function is still [not implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1443).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker [`msgget()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html) is an XSI feature, [which is defined as](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_450):  "The X/Open System Interfaces (XSI) option is the core application programming interface for C and sh programming for systems conforming to the Single UNIX Specification. This is a superset of the mandatory requirements for conformance to POSIX.1-2017."  The "core application programming interface for C" doesn't sound optional to me.

Comment: (cont) Although the `XSI` popup states: "The functionality described is part of the X/Open Systems Interfaces option."  So, is it an option, is it a "core [API]"? The question needs to specify the OS in question.